# Doctrine 2.2 Bisna CLI

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I can't get the Bisna doctrine cli to work. It complains about not being able to find the Symfony Console application. Notice it's trying to look for it in a nested directory of Doctrine/Symfony/Console/Symfony/Component/Console. Anybody ever seen this?

```
PHP Warning:  require(/Users/jhicks/workspace/production/application/../library/Doctrine/Symfony/Console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/jhicks/workspace/production/library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 163
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/jhicks/workspace/production/application/../library/Doctrine/Symfony/Console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php' (include_path='/Users/jhicks/workspace/production/library:.:/opt/local/lib/php') in /Users/jhicks/workspace/production/library/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php on line 163
```

Here's the Github page for the doctrine cli from Bisna: https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2/blob/master/bin/doctrine.php

Answer (score 0):

There are many repositories that call themsemves *Bisna* in Github, it is difficult to find what of them you are using without further information.

The *original* one is the one created by Guilherme Blanco (*Bisna* used to be his nickname) called **Zend Framework 1 + Doctrine** 2 and works like a charm, but it does not bundle the Symfony components necessary to run the CLI tool.

What you have to do is download them from GitHub (search for "Symfony" and you will find the components inside the Organization repository) and put them inside your project's *library* folder paying attention to the [PSR #0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) naming conventions.

If you provide the piece of code that generates this error and the repository and version you are using, it will be easier to detect the error and give a better answer. It is naive to try and guess the type of error, but probably you have problems with namespaces and/or how you are calling Symfony's Console component.

If you need some guidance on how this integration can be achieved, you can look at [doctrine.php](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2/blob/master/bin/doctrine.php) inside Blanco's repository.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Doctrine which does include the Symfony components out of the box. There was no need to download them separately. I am using the Bisna that you refer to - the latest version which has been updated to also work with the latest version of Doctrine: https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2. I think I may have found the solution but can't test until the morning. I think I may have a class instantiated somewhere missing the leading back slash which is required when using PHP 5.3 namespacing.

Comment: Nope, can't see where the problem is. Like I said, this is very similar to when you are missing the leading backslash and trying to use a class and it uses the namespace of the file you are in to try and locate it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to add these two lines to my existing autoloader bootstrap method:

```
$symfonyAutoloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', 'Doctrine');   
$autoloader->pushAutoloader(array($symfonyAutoloader, 'loadClass'), 'Symfony');
```

I didn't think this would be necessary since I included Symfony in the autoloaderNamespaces array in my application.ini file.

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Symfony"
```